# How to implement publish / subscribe feature with a server in react native

Tags: javascript, web-services, react-native, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to build a chat applicaton in react native using redis pub/sub. Searched
redis client for javascript but i didn't get. Can anyone let me know how to use redis pub/sub in react native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement redis on the backend side, not on the frontend.
Redis is a database as they say on their websites [here](https://redis.io)

> Redis is an open source (BSD licensed), in-memory data structure store, used as a database, cache and message broker

For the frontend side if you want to use publish / subscribe feature you can use websockets for example.

Here is some good libraries to use with React Native:

- [Socket.io](https://socket.io)
- React native also bring support for [WebSockets](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network#websocket-support)

On the backend side you can use:

- [Socket.io](https://socket.io)
- [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws)
- [sockjs](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node)
- [socketcluster](https://github.com/SocketCluster/socketcluster)

Here is an example using the React Native WebSockets:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('wss://example.com/stuff');

ws.onopen = () => {
  // connection opened
  ws.send('Hello world'); // send a message
};

ws.onmessage = (e) => {
  // a message was received
  console.log(e.data);
};
```

You also have other alternatives, like long-pooling

Comment: Thank you. Socket.io library works. But socket.io channel disconnects whenever the app is in background or closed, how to keep channel connected all time because i have to include push notification feature to my chat application.

Comment: You have a react native or react.js app ?

Comment: React native application

Comment: Okay i'll raise a question regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

Redis is a database and is often used in backend solutions.
As I understand you are trying to implement a client-side solution in React Native.

To make it simpler you can use a ready backend and SDK compatible with React Native to build your app.

For example, ConnectyCube has added React Native support to its [JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/ConnectyCube/connectycube-js-sdk-releases/releases/tag/1.4.1). It has a lot of features useful for building chat applications for various purposes.

Check their [documentation](https://developers.connectycube.com/js/react-native) how you can build it.

Here is a useful [guide how to build an XMPP chat in React Native](https://medium.com/@connectycube/xmpp-real-time-chat-in-react-native-8d6d5d23dd47).