# On React native app how to get updates from backend on every event example like new order is placed

Tags: node.js, react-native, express

I'm not sure if this is possible but currently my react native app polls my node js backend for information every minute. Instead I want my node js backend to detect a change in my database for a specific user, and then send that updated information to my react native app user. Is this possible, does anyone have any guidance or direction, Are there any third party apps that could help in this process? What would I need to do exactly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement push notification with react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53538428/how-to-implement-push-notification-with-react-native)

Comment: It is usually called pub-sub / subscription. It works by creating bidirectional communication between client and server usually using WebSocket. Polling is just client keeps talking to the server side. But with subscription, since session is opened to both "from client to server" and "from server to client", server can send the data to the client side whenever new data is available.

I think this link will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53532428/how-to-implement-publish-subscribe-feature-with-a-server-in-react-native